# Tacacs+ login asking ENABLE password & logs not working

Tags: cisco, tacacs

I am new to TACACS so please bear me with my novice level questions :)

I have configured TACACS+ on Ubuntu. now I can login to switch with users defined in TACACS+ server. I have created two users, one for support, one for admin purposes.

Q1-

I want to allow only fixed sets of CMD's for SUPPORT group.

Q2-

Log files in /var/log/tac* are empty. how can I enable logs that which user is logging to which switch using tacacs+ authentication?

Following is my TACACS server configuration key = testing123

```
accounting file = /var/log/tacplus.log
default authentication = file /etc/passwd
group = support {    default service = denyservice = shell {priv-lvl = 15}cmd = interface { permit [faFAgiGI].* }}
group = unicorns {
    default service = permit
    service = exec {
    priv-lvl = 15
    }
}
user = mary {
    name = "Network Support"
    member = support
}
user = tina {
    name = "Network Unicorn"
    member = unicorns
}
```

Following is my switch configuration

```
aaa new-model
aaa authentication login default local group tacacs+ enable
tacacs-server host 2.3.4.5
tacacs-server key 0 testing123
```

Comment: What kind of switch are you using?

Comment: cisco 3850 24 ports / IOS 16.3 + cisco 3650 24 ports / IOS 16.3 / Cisco 3750x 24 ports

Comment: Did any answer help you? If so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you can post and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I want to allow only fixed sets of CMD's for SUPPORT group.

This issue is two-fold:

1. You need to configure your device to use TACACS for authorization:

```
(config)#aaa authorization commands 15 ...
(config)#aaa authorization config-commands
(config)#aaa authorization exec default ...
```

2. Your tac_plus config looks weird. Changing it so that it's in more of a block style:

```
group = support {
    default service = deny

    service = shell {
        priv-lvl = 15
    }

    cmd = interface {
        permit [faFAgiGI].* 
    }
}
```

There are some issues with this.

1. Since your default service is `deny` and you only have an
   `interface` subcommand defined, users in the `support` group won't
   be able to do anything at all - because they'd need to get into
   `configure` mode in order to use the `interface` subcommand.
2. Since you're dropping users in the `support` group to priv 15 in the config, they won't need to `enable`. If you want them to have to `enable` when they log in, then remove the `set priv-lvl = 15` line in the config and configure AAA on the device to use TACACS for accessing `enable` mode:

```
(config)#aaa authentication enable ...
```

3. The `cmd` definitions need to be moved inside of the `service = shell` block.

Here's a revised config for you to try out:

```
group = support {
    default service = deny

    service = shell {
        set priv-lvl = 15

        cmd = show {
            permit .*
        }

        cmd = configure {
            permit ^terminal
        }

        cmd = interface {
            permit [faFAgiGI].* 
        }
    }
}
```

> Log files in /var/log/tac* are empty. how can I enable logs that which user is logging to which switch using tacacs+ authentication?

This might depend on the tac_plus implementation you're using. Some implementations allow you to specify log files for authentication/authorization/accounting. Either way, you still need to configure the `accounting` portion on the device:

```
(config)#aaa accounting commands ...
```

Comment: Ok I made the changes as advised, When I Login to switch with TACACS , and going to **conf t** mode by **ENABLE** its asking for password
how can I define ENABLE password under tacacs server for that user? is it possible that I can define different ENABLE password in tacacs config file for each user, and the support users can switch to ENABLE mode by using there enable password?

Comment: By default the enable password will be the same password used for the user's regular login credentials. If you wish to set different enable passwords per user then you'll need to consult the tac_plus documentation on how to do this (hint: look for the `enable = ` keyword under the user configuration blocks). See https://www.shrubbery.net/tac_plus/ for more info.